# Swift - UITextView text is getting cut when applying custom font

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uifont

I am using `UITextView` inside super view `UIView` to display text with many different types of fonts.
But `UITextView` text is getting cut when applying specific font **Smoothie_Life_Swirls_2.0**

I am creating textView programmatically as below,

```
    textView = ResizableTextView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: contentView.frame.size.width, height: contentView.frame.size.height))
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    textView.alignment = .center
    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    textView.fontName = "Helveticas"
    textView.fontSize = contentView.frame.size.height
    textView.textColor = textColor
    textView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleTopMargin, .flexibleRightMargin, .flexibleBottomMargin, .flexibleLeftMargin, .flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    textView.delegate = self
    contentView.addSubview(textView)
    textView.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Here ResizableTextView is my UITextView class, in which fontName and fontSize will be set

```
public class ResizableTextView: UITextView {

    public private(set) var textAttributes: [String: AnyObject] = [:]

    public var fontName: String = "Helvetica" {
        didSet {
            let font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: fontSize)
            textAttributes[NSFontAttributeName] = font
            self.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: self.text, attributes: textAttributes)
            self.font = font
        }
    }

    public var fontSize: CGFloat = 20 {
        didSet {
            let font = UIFont(name: fontName, size: fontSize)
            textAttributes[NSFontAttributeName] = font
            self.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: self.text, attributes: textAttributes)
            self.font = font
        }
    }

}
```

When I set **Smoothie_Life_Swirls_2.0** font to textView using ResizableTextView's fontName property, at that time text is getting cut.

Text1 - Getting Output[image]

Text2 - Required Output[image]

I want to fit the text in `UITextView` same as Text2, but I am getting the result as displayed in Text1.

Comment: Why was this put on hold? It's a good question and fills all requirements. @Nikunj The solution is probably `textView.clipsToBounds = false`

Comment: I have tried 
textView.clipsToBounds = false
But it doesn't work

Comment: Yeah I forgot, UITextView's are weird. Without entirely knowing what you're making, I'd suggest using NSString.boundingRect to calculate the required textView size. `boundingRect` takes weird characters into account. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1524729-boundingrect

Comment: Another solution, just guessing here, is calling layoutIfNeeded after setting a new string. If your constraints allow it, the text view might adjust itself to fit your weird font.

Comment: Thanks, @OscarApeland for the response

I need to just display text out of the textView's bounds.
I think this is an issue of this font Smoothie_Life_Swirls_2.0.

UITextView is not allowing text to get out of the bounds.
I have tried to take a UITextView in separate demo project and set Smoothie_Life_Swirls_2.0 font to text, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Nikunj Did you find any solution for it?

Comment: Not yet, let me know if you find any solution, it will be very helpful @SunilZalavadiya